# Change Switch Color in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.android, toggle, xamarin.forms

I want to change the color of switch in android and created custom renderer just like as one  of the post from stack overflow:
Below is the code

```
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.TextOn = "Yes";
        Control.TextOff = "No";

        Android.Graphics.Color colorOn = Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(239, 201, 6);
        Android.Graphics.Color colorOff = Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray;
        Android.Graphics.Color colorDisabled = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
        Android.Graphics.Color textColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;

        Control.SetTextColor (ColorStateList.ValueOf  (textColor));
        Control.SetTextColor (textColor);

        StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked }, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled }, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(colorOff));

        Control.ThumbDrawable = drawable;

    }
}
```

}
This code isn't working for me ? Do i need to add some items in drawable folder as well ?

Answer (score 2):

With Forms 2.1, there are now [effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/introduction/) which can remove the need for a custom renderer in situations where only minor visual changes are being made. See the linked guide for getting started on using them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own control in your UI project:

```csharp
public class MySwitch : Switch
{
}
```

After that change your forms where you used `Switch` control to `MySwitch` control.

And then you need to tell `Xamarin.Forms` infrastructure that you are providing renderer for `MySwitch` control.

In your `*.Droid` project add following attribute at assembly level (above your namespace declaration or in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file)

```csharp
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
```

Comment: I have already added the assembly  but still its not working. do i need to add anything in drawable folder also ??

Comment: @Dhruv I've updated example, with defining your own control and then defining renderer for it.

Comment: @Dhruv, when running your project execution flow gets into `OnElementChanged` method in `CustomSwitchRenderer` class (I mean, can you debug this method at all)?

Comment: Yep !!! On debugging the control goes here but nothing changes in UI. I'm not sure why its happening?

Comment: Did you tried to change for example values of `TextOn` and `TextOff` properties? To see if change to them is reflected on UI.

Comment: I dont want any text so commented the TextOn and Textoff properties. When I uncommented it and run following exception occurred: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type EVGMobileSolution.Droid.MainActivity from native handle 0x58e00021 (key_handle 0x42c7f300).

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can change the propery "colorAccent" on your "styles.xml" file

```
<item name="colorAccent">#008000</item>
```